# How to Import Pymysql?

Tags: python, database-connection, pymysql

I am trying to connect to SQL Server through Eclipse using the below code and it is returning 'No module name pymysql.' I have been researching and I believe I need PIP installed. However, I have Python 2.7.10, which I believe comes with PIP. Is there some type of driver that I need, too? I read this module does not need any driver, but not sure how valid that is.

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='sqlhost', trusted=True)
```

Comment: did you run pip install pymysql?

Comment: I ran pip install pymysql and it returns an invalid syntax error. I'm new to python so I'm sure I'm making a beginner mistake, I just can't figure out what it is yet.

Comment: please mention the whole error you got

Comment: The official documentation recommends to use `python -m pip install SomePackage`

Comment: Copied directly ...                                                                                File "C:\CodeRepository\Practice\PracticeIII.py", line 1
    pip install pymysql                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    #pip install pymysql AW2014;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: seems you run `pip install pymysql` as a python code, no it is not .. you should run it in command line `cmd.exe`

Comment: "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" is what it is giving me. Do I need a FreeTDS download? Please note I am on Windows. Thanks for the help.

Comment: do `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts"  before running `pip` command but dont forget to use the path where your python is installed
`

Comment: I just went to that folder and it is C:\Python27 ... so I'm going to put in    setx PATH "C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts" then run pip install pymysql?

Comment: just do `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts" `

Comment: Just ran that and it was successful. I tried to run pip install pymysql afterwards but it is still not recognizing PIP as an internal or external command.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right `python 2.7.x` comes with pip pre-installed but we need to add the `path/to/Python27/Scripts/` directory in the `PATH` environment variable to use `pip` from the terminal.
Once `pip` is present in system `PATH` you can execute below command to install pymysql.

`pip install pymysql`